# UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier possible leak while Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-leaks, scroll

I experience memory usage increasing each time I scroll up and down my UITableView. I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, but it doesn't seem it optimizes memory usage. Here's the code:

I thought it was because of UIImageView allocated each time, but when I comment these lines of code and leave only standard UITableViewCell implementation, the problem with memory doesn't go away. Though after leaving the view memory releases (obv it happens only thanks to [self.tableView removeFromSuperview]; method). But while I stay in the view and keep scrolling up and down memory just increases.

```
@interface ArtistsViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ArtistsViewController

@synthesize fetchedResultsController = _fetchedResultsController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        // Update to handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:11/255.0 green:12/255.0 blue:20/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:YES];
    [self.tableView removeFromSuperview];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id  sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)loadCellData:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Artist *artist = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", artist.name);
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", artist.name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu songs", (unsigned long)[artist.songs count]];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@.png", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], artist.name];

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 2, 55, 55)];

    imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        NSLog(@"NOCELL");
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Load cell data
    [self loadCellData:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    //customization
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:11/255.0 green:12/255.0 blue:20/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:222/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:62/255.0 green:103/255.0 blue:115/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - fetchedResultsController

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Artist" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Custom Cell instead of using the default cell properties.

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
        MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *nib;

                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell"
                                                    owner:self options:nil];


            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCell class]])
                cell = (YorBillTableCell *)oneObject;
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Still leaking. Seems to be a leak since 2009.